# disableUndoRegistration is still allowing undo operations

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, undo

I want to disable undo registration for an operation on an NSManagedObject but it still records the operation even though I explicitly call disableUndoRegistration.

Is there something obvious I am missing?

I also tried to enable/disable in the viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear methods, respectively.

Here is some example code...

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NotesViewControllerDelegate methods
 - (void)notesViewController:(NotesViewController *)controller didFinishWithSave:(BOOL)save
{
    if (save)
    {
        [undoManager disableUndoRegistration];
        [book setNotes:[controller getDataFromText]];
        [undoManager enableUndoRegistration];
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a call to [undoManager isUndoRegistrationEnabled]; which returns NO.  Yet I am still able to undo.  What to do?

Comment: One solution just occurred to me which is to not set the object data until the object is saved with all of the other changes.  I think this would work as an interim fix but I would like to know why undo is not working right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call [managedObjectContext processPendingChanges]; before each of the calls that disable and enable the undo registration because Core Data queues changes to be able to do optimizations.

see
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html